# Read List from stringname append

Tags: python

I have the following problem, I want to reference a variable from a string so that I can call up a list.

I enter the user into the function def fetch(user). e.g. name1

I would like from name1, read the list name1_skiplist

or from name2 read name2_skiplist

```
name1_skiplist = [('home', '/pic'),('home', '/jpg'),]
name2_skiplist = [('etc', '/pic'),('etc', '/jpg'),]
name3_skiplist = [('tmp', '/pic'),('tmp', '/jpg'),]

def fetch(user):
    joinedlist = []
    joinedlist = user + '_skiplist'
    if joinedlist:
        ....
```

Comment: Why don't you use dict and then match you key >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dict is more suited for you use case to retrieve list based on your key.

```
  data = {'name1_skiplist': [('home', '/pic'), ('home', '/jpg'), ],
            'name2_skiplist': [('etc', '/pic'), ('etc', '/jpg'), ],
            'name3_skiplist': [('tmp', '/pic'), ('tmp', '/jpg'), ]}

def fetch(user):
    joinedlist = user + '_skiplist'
    result = data.get(joinedlist)
    return result
```

Comment: I get the error NameError:   File "C:\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    data = {name1_skiplist: [('home', '/pic'), ('home', '/jpg'), ],
NameError: name 'name1_skiplist' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Organize related information in collections -- data structures like dicts, lists,
tuples, namedtuples, dataclasses, etc. In your case, assuming I understand
your goal, a dict is probably a decent choice. For example:

```
skips = {
    'home': [('home', '/pic'), ('home', '/jpg')],
    'etc': [('etc', '/pic'), ('etc', '/jpg')],
    'tmp': [('tmp', '/pic'), ('tmp', '/jpg')],
}
```

An illustrated usage:

```
for name in skips:
    sks = skips[name]
    print(name, sks)
```

Comment: I only need this list from the user (fetch(user), and not all

Comment: @kulle.alle Your question is quite unclear, but I suspect that using a data structure will make writing `fetch()` easier. Any time you have multiple variables with the same suffix, that usually suggests the data should be bundled together. That's the key point. The rest is details that have not been well explained to us. Good luck.